# Multiple path names for a same component in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, react-router, url-routing

I am using the same component for three different routes:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/users" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/widgets" component={Home} />
</Router>
```

Is there anyway to combine it, to be like:

```
<Router>
    <Route path=["/home", "/users", "/widgets"] component={Home} />
</Router>
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 321):

As of react-router [v4.4.0-beta.4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v4.4.0-beta.4), and officially in v5.0.0, you can now specify an array of paths which resolve to a component e.g.

```
<Router>
    <Route path={["/home", "/users", "/widgets"]} component={Home} />
</Router>
```

Each path in the array is a regular expression string.

The documentation for this approach can be found [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string).

**Update for React Router v6**

[React Router v6](https://reactrouter.com/) no longer allows an array of paths to be passed as a Route property. Instead you can make use of the `useRoutes` (see [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) for documentation) React hook to achieve the same behaviour:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  useRoutes,
} from "react-router-dom";

const element = <Home />;
const App = () => 
 useRoutes(['/home', '/users', '/widgets'].map(path => ({path, element})));

const AppWrapper = () => (
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  );
```

You can see an extended example of this code working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dphbxg?file=src/App.tsx).

The key take away from this answer is:

> The useRoutes hook is the functional equivalent of `<Routes>`, but it
> uses JavaScript objects instead of `<Route>` elements to define your
> routes.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer. @Cameron 's answer doesn't support full regexp feature anyways (at least I wasn't able to do it).

Comment: How do I set the `exact` attribute for a single path?

Comment: @JulianSoto Create a Route to a component with one single path along with the exact path. You can then create another Route to the same component with an array of paths without the exact attribute.

Comment: I can't `yarn upgrade` from 4.3 to 4.4. Is it officially released?

Comment: @ndtreviv Looking at the react router change log I can see the feature was rolled out in v4.4.0 Beta 4. I'd recommend upgrading to the latest version, which at the time of writing this is v5.5.0. You can do this running "yarn upgrade react-router --latest"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore since v6, see answers below for alternatives

Comment: @PdevG Thanks for making me aware of this. I've updated my answer with the recommend approach for v6 (and it's a different approach to the answers elsewhere in this thread!).

Comment: Do you happen to know how one passes the same props to multiple elements without having to duplicate the props? That was clear from the array but not so much from the hook. Honestly the hook seems like a distinct step backwards as far as clarity of code is concerned.

Comment: Hey @GrantCurell. You could use a map like I have done in this forked version of the code from my answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-dphbxg-rq961a?file=src%2FApp.tsx. In that example I'm using the same instance of the Home component, though you could do the same in the answer I gave above, but map is slightly less verbose. TBH Im not sure if I like this new hook in React Router, Im just accepting it and working with it!

Comment: for v6, I recommend going with @bas answer. It doesn't violate the dry principle. Just don't forget to add index/key as is shown in Christopher Chiche example.

Answer (score 137):

At least with react-router v4 the `path` can be a regular expression string, so you can do something like this:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/(home|users|widgets)/" component={Home} />
</Router>
```

As you can see it's a bit verbose so if your `component`/`route` is simple like this it's probably not worth it.

And of course if this actually comes up often you could always create a wrapping component that takes in an array `paths` parameter, which does the regex or `.map` logic reusably.

Comment: Great idea @Cameron.  I found it useful to modify it a bit to match only paths which begin with one of the groups: `/^\/(home|users|widgets)/`  Now, `/widgets` will match, but `/dashboard/widgets` won't match.

Comment: Should be great, but for now the type regex is not valid on prop-types validation: `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` of type `regexp` supplied to `Route`, expected `string`.`

Comment: @FábioPaiva yeah I still haven't figured out how to put an arbitrary regex in the route

Comment: put it in as a string `<Route path="/(new|edit)/user/:id?" ... />`

Comment: not working with ```path={`/(${ROUTES.HOME}|${ROUTES.HOME_1})/`}```

Answer (score 60):

I don't think it is if you use a version of React Router lower than v4.

You can use a `map` as you would do with any other JSX component though:

```
<Router>
    {["/home", "/users", "/widgets"].map((path, index) => 
        <Route path={path} component={Home} key={index} />
    )}
</Router>
```

**EDIT**

You can also use a regex for the path [in react-router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string) as long as it's supported by [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp). See @Cameron's answer for more info.

Comment: Don't forget the `key` prop.

Comment: note this would cause (undesired...?) remounts when switching from paths (eg /home => /users in that example)

Comment: Indeed! The desirability probably depends on your use case and your components. If you don't want to remount, using regexp as indicated in my edit might work better.

Comment: Also, don't forget to remove `exact` if added.

Answer (score 22):

As of react router v6 they removed the option for regex and according to the type definition it is again `path: string`. Currently you would have to spell each path out again or use a map for convenience:

```
<Routes>
    {['home', 'users', 'widgets'].map(path => <Route path={path} element={<Home />} />)}
</Routes>
```

See also https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#note-on-route-path-patterns

Comment: Really?? Wtf…..

Comment: @Delice react-router-dom love to change their code to make us modify ours on each version update

Comment: Apparently it is so they can actually parse and rank the paths better, so you can do `/card/new` and `/card/:cardId` and it will automatically choose the best fitting option.  Which is of course a lot harder (if not impossible) to do if regexps are involved.

Comment: Correction:
`{['home', 'users', 'widgets'].map` ...

Answer (score 8):

As of react-route-dom v5.1.2 you can pass multiple path as below

```
 <Route path={"/home" | "/users" | "/widgets"} component={Home} />
```

And obvoiusly you need to import Home jsx file on top.

Comment: It works! but I am receiveing a Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `path` supplied to `Route`.

Comment: @AzizStark You are right, it is not a correct answer. It is better you use `<Route path={["/home", "/users", "/widgets"]} component={Home} />` as the solution.

Comment: What is this single-pipe syntax for strings? Cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: That syntax can't work.  Bitwise-or between strings returns 0.  I suspect a regexp with alternatives was intended — but for that `|` chars should be inside the string, not operators between strings (and see other answers about regexps no longer being supported in v6)

Answer (score 6):

With react-router **v6**, you can do like this:

```
<Routes>
  {['path1', 'path2'].map((path) => (
            <Route key={--> you should use some unique key <--} path={path} element={<SomeComponent />} />
  ))}
</Routes>
```

react-router docs says:

> React Router v6 uses a simplified path format. `<Route path>` in v6 supports only 2 kinds of placeholders: dynamic `:id`-style params and `*` wildcards.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#note-on-route-path-patterns

Comment: @Nathan I am sorry, but I don't think so.

Comment: @OndrejHj04 have a look at the v5 docs. Path supports string[] 
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string

Comment: Ok np, but now we are using V6 which is also in your title

Comment: And for v6 this is not working

Comment: This worked fine for me in v6

Comment: A reminder If my edit won't get accepted-don't forget about `key={index}` (you can add `index` as a second parameter to the map method).

Comment: @zebra-f Do not use Array index in keys. But yes, you should use some unique key..

Comment: @SandroMarques thanks for the heads up, however from what I have just read an `index` in this case might be fine as this array is 'static'.

Comment: @zebra-f Even if the array is static, it's still recommended to avoid using the array index as a key, as it triggers linter warnings. I prefer creating a key with a unique value or even using the locale value if it's a multi-language site. This provides a more robust and flexible approach to rendering elements in lists in React.

Answer (score 3):

Other option: use route prefix. `/pages` for example.
You will get

- `/pages/home`
- `/pages/users`
- `/pages/widgets`

And then resolve it in a detailed way inside the `Home` component.

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/pages/" component={Home} />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that works with **React Router v6**. It uses a helper function to abstract away mapping the paths to `Route` components. This helps keep the routes easy/intuitive to read and allows for easily mixing in `MultiRoute`s with regular `Route`s.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

/**
 * For using the same JSX element with **multiple** paths
 * @param {JSXElement} el - JSX element
 * @param  {...string} paths - all paths that point to given JSX element
 * @returns `Route` elements
 */
function MultiRoute (el, ...paths) {
  return paths.map((p) => <Route key={p} element={el} path={p} />);
};

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<LogIn />} path='/log-in' />
        <Route element={<SignUp />} path='/sign-up' />
        {MultiRoute(<Home />, '/home', '/users', '/widgets')}
        {MultiRoute(<Contact />, '/feedback', '/contact')}
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if need add few routes from path

In APP add basic routes, like

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>} />
  <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>} />
</Routes>
```

here routed /dashboard path and call Dashboard component

then, in Dashboard component add few exact routes, like

```
return (
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path='/' element={<Client/>} />
    <Route exact path='/user' element={<One/>} />
    <Route exact path='/role' element={<Two/>} />
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFound/>} />
  </Routes>
)
```

here routed exact path, "/" mean "/dashboard"

/dashboard

/dashboard/user

/dashboard/role

Answer (score 0):

As per React Router docs the proptype 'path' is of type string .So there is no way you could pass an array as props to the Route Component.

If your intention is to only change route you can use the same component for different route no issues with that

Comment: This answer is no longer correct as path now accepts an array of string. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53074599/203371).

Answer (score 0):

here is a little function to transform your custom routes with a `paths` prop to multiple standard routes supported by `react-router` v6, with `path` prop:

```js
const normalizeRoutes = (routes) =>
  routes.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const newRoute = curr.children
      ? { ...curr, children: normalizeRoutes(curr.children) }
      : curr;
    if (newRoute.paths) {
      return [
        ...acc,
        ...newRoute.paths.map((path) => {
          const { paths, ...rest } = newRoute;
          return { ...rest, path };
        })
      ];
    }
    return [...acc, newRoute];
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom` no longer supports regexp in path, an alternative is to save the component in a variable and use that as the component for many routes.

```
let home= <Home />

<Route path={"/home" | "/users" | "/widgets"} component={Home} />

return <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={home} />
        <Route path="/users" element={home} />
        <Route path="/widgets" element={home} />
    </Routes>
```