# Match multiple path with react router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Given I have 2 path rendering the same component, how do I avoid to repeat route configs like this :

```
<Route path="/path1" component={MyComp} />
<Route path="/path2" component={MyComp} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple path names for a same component in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router)

Answer (score 22):

Best solution I found so far (but seems a bit strange) :

```
<Route path="/:path(path1|path2)" component={MyComp} />
```

Comment: Why not just do `path="/(path1|path2)"`?

Answer (score 12):

```
<Route path={["/common-one", "/common-two"]} component={Common} />
```

For version 5 above
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

Comment: this is working perfectly fine, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 8):

Great answer. This also helps in the following scenario:

```
<Route path="/path/path1" component={MyComp} />
<Route path="/path/:subpath(path2|path3)" component={MyAnotherComp} />
```

Without `(path2|path3)` both components `MyComp` and `MyAnotherComp` are mounted if the path is `/path/path2`.

PS. Would have added as a comment, but not eligible :).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to allow multiple match (different parameters) but also without parameter - e.g. match URLs:

- /questions
- /questions/posted
- /questions/answered

You can do this with optional parameter (note question mark after the bracket)

```
<Route path="/questions/:tab(posted|answered)?" component={...} />
```