# Layout routes with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to do layouts with react-router.

When my user hits `/` I want to render some layout. When my user hits `/login`, or `/sign_up` I want the layout to render, with the relevant component for `/login` or `/sign_up` rendered.

Currently, my `App.js` looks like this

```
return (
  <div className={className}>
    <Route path="/" component={Auth} />
    <ModalContainer />
  </div>
);
```

My `Auth.js` looks like this

```
return (
  <AuthFrame footerText={footerText} footerClick={footerClick}>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route path="/sign_up" component={SignUpContainer} />
  </AuthFrame>
);
```

So `AuthFrame` will get rendered when I hit `/`, and then react router looks for `login` or `sign_up` to render the other containers.

However, when I hit `/`, only the `AuthFrame` will render.

I would like for `/` to be treated as `/login`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: so your problem is not about rendering layout, but rather how to make `react-router` render your `Login` component inside `AuthFrame` both for `/` and `/login` routes, do I understand you correctly? If that's the case, take a look at [Multiple path names for a same component in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router) on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Switch` component is useful in these cases:

```
return (
  <AuthFrame footerText={footerText} footerClick={footerClick}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
      <Route path="/sign_up" component={SignUpContainer} />
      {/* Default route in case none within `Switch` were matched so far */}
      <Route component={LoginContainer} />
    </Switch>
  </AuthFrame>
);
```

see: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forced to introduce a prop/state which indicates the status of your viewer. This means is he signed in or just a guest of your website.

Your router can't obviously render `/login` if you you hit `/` but the router allows you to redirect to another page:

```
class AuthContainer extends React.Component {
    defaultProps = {
        loggedIn: false
    }

    render() {

        return <div>
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
            <Route path="/sign_up" component={SignUpContainer}/>
        </div>
    }
}

class PublicHomePage extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return <div>
            <Route path="/settings" component={SettingsComponent}/>
            <Route path="/profile" component={ProfileComponent}/>
            <Route path="/and_so_on" component={AndSoOnComponent}/>
        </div>
    }
}


class App
    extends React.Component {
    defaultProps = {
        loggedIn: false
    }

    render() {

        const {loggedIn} = this.props;

        if (loggedIn) {
            return <PublicHomePage/>
        }


        return <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
            <Redirect to="/login"/>
        )}/>


    }
}
```

I hope this code works for you. It isn't quite perfect but it should give you an idea how you could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would probably manipulate a bit with `Route`s in `react-router`. This code in `AuthFrame` should do the trick:

```
return (    
    <AuthFrame footerText={footerText} footerClick={footerClick}>
         {["/", "/login"].map((path, ind) =>
            <Route exact key={ind} path={path} component={LoginContainer} />
         )}
         <Route exact path="/sign_up" component={SignUpContainer} />
    </AuthFrame>);
```

Note the usage of `exact` on the routes, this is to prevent matching login component on `/sign_up` since it will also match `/` and prevent rendering both `login` and `signup` when accessing the root path (`/`).