# Handle a Route that can match an exact path or a path with parameter with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I work with react-router v4, and I like to merge different route to a single one. Is there a way to simplify the following code:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={myPage} />
<Route path="/a/:a" component={myPage} />
<Route path="/b/:b" component={myPage} />
```

`MyPage` should be answering for `/`, `/a/foo`, but not for `c/bar`.

Comment: hi, have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router

Comment: @user2760868 my problem is with the `/` path that catch everything if it is not coupled with the `exact` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Define exact path and also assign a key prop when you use same component for different routes:

```
<Route exact path="/" key="root" component={myPage} />
<Route exact path="/a/:a" key="a-a" component={myPage} />
<Route exact path="/b/:b" key="b-b" component={myPage} />
```

Comment: I didn't know for th key. Thanks. It doesn't solve my problem. To avoid rerendering, I need to have a single `<Route>`

Comment: You should be checking with is path params inside your component to do so.