# How to render an element for all paths except one

Tags: reactjs, react-router

is it possible to render an element for all paths except one?

For example:

```
<Link to='/a'>A</Link>
<Link to='/b'>B</Link>
<Link to='/c'>C</Link>
...
<Link to='/noRender'>No Render</Link>
...
<Link to='/z'>Z</Link>

<Route path='all expect /noRender' render={()=> (<p>rendered element</p>)}   />
```

Im looking for simplest/best solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple path names for a same component in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router)

Comment: Check above existing SO question it has everything you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the logic within the `render` prop?

```
<Link to='/a'>A</Link>
<Link to='/b'>B</Link>
<Link to='/c'>C</Link>
...
<Link to='/noRender'>No Render</Link>
...
<Link to='/z'>Z</Link>

<Route path='/' render={()=> {
  if (this.props.location.pathname === "/noRender") {
    return null;
  } else {
    return <p>rendered element</p>;
  }
}} />
```