# Preact router: Multiple path names for a same component

Tags: reactjs, preact

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router) but pertains to Preact Router- Is it possible to use the same component for multiple different routes?

Like `<ServiceType path=["/cleaning", "/printing", "/accounting"] />`

So that my URL would look like
`example.com/cleaning`
`example.com/printing`
`example.com/accounting`

And they are all handled in the same component `<ServiceType />`.

Is this possible?

Comment: whats ServiceType? is it contains react route?

Comment: It's just a class component. It doesn't have any routes itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-router/issues/255#issuecomment-352496112) it's not possible because it doesn't work with path ranking.
the recommendation if you really need Regex Match in path is to switch to enroute or React Router.

Also, **Note** that [this](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-router/issues/255) is an open defect from 2017,  i wouldn't get much hope its gonna be fixed any time soon..

if you're not into switching lib you will need to do this like so:

```
<ServiceType path="/cleaning" />
<ServiceType path="/printing" />
<ServiceType path="/accounting" />
```