# React Router Endpoint with Options

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to define a react route that can contain multiple different options.

I am trying to avoid defining a route for each, like below:

```
<Route  path='/option1' component={Testing}/>
<Route  path='/option2' component={Testing}/>
<Route  path='/option3' component={Testing}/>
```

In Express, I am able to do this using `app.get('/:name(option1|option2|option3)?', (req, res) => {}` and then access this data via `req.params.name`

Also, is there a way that i can pass the path parameter (i.e option1), into my component via props? How would i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple path names for a same component in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router)

Answer (score 2):

You could store an `array` of paths and `map` them to the same `Component`

```
['/path','/foo','bar'].map(path => <Route key={path} path={path} component={Foo} />)
```

**Is there a way that i can pass the path parameter (i.e option1), into my component via props?**

Yes, just use `render` instead of `component`

```
<Route path='/' render={() => <MyComp myProp='foo'/>}
```

For `url parameters` use it like this

```
<Route path='/path/:param' component={Foo} />
```

And inside `Foo.js`

```
console.log(props.match.params.param)
```

You could also use `regexp`

```
<Route exact path="/path/:foo([0-9a-fA-f]{40})" component={Foo} />
```

Answer (score 0):

paramenters are set with `/myroute:myparam` and you can retrieve it in target component with `this.props.match.params.myparam`