# React Router declarative redirect while preserving a portion of the path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've recently had to change a path in my app, but I would like to preserve the validity of old deep links by redirecting them. Here's an example of a changed path:

Original: `/foo/users/12345`

Updated: `/bar/users/12345`

I tried to implement this using a redirect:

```
<Route path='/bar' component={MyComponent} />
<Route path='/foo'>
  <Redirect to='/bar' />
</Route>
```

However, the latter part of the request is lost in a redirect. So a request to `/foo/users/12345` redirects to `/bar`.

Is there a declarative way to pass the `/users/12345` portion of my path along in the redirect?

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you rephrase? do you want to change the path in the url but render a specific component for a different path?

Comment: No, I basically want to redirect `/foo*` to `/bar*` where the portion matched by the splat is preserved.

Comment: Having same issue with @djfdev, I'm not sure if there is another way than using replace by RegExp. I expect react-router should return the unmatch portion then I can use it to append to the redirect url

Answer (score 2):

I was looking into the documentation and I did not find any out of the box solution for this scenario what you were explaining in the question.

Instead of trying to use `Redirect` I have build a functional component which has been set as the component of the original route. This helps in redirect and can be used for this purpose like below:

```
<Route path='/foo/:users?/:id?' component={RedirectHelper}/>
<Route path='/bar/:users?/:id?' component={MyComponent}/>
```

The `RedirectHelper` looks like this:

```
const RedirectHelper = (props) => {
  const {history} = props;
  const path = history.location.pathname.replace('/foo', '');
  history.push(`/bar${path}`);
  return null;
}
```

So technically the `RedirectHelper` component picks up the value from the `history.location.pathname` property for the original `~foo/users/12345` URL and builds the new one. At the end it simply redirects to `~bar/users/12345` URL. The validity of the original one has been kept. I have tested out this solution and worked like charm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting ... this works exactly how I had hoped. Can you explain why I need to return an empty div? I notice that if I return undefined it doubles the new path segment and doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @djfdev The `RedirectHelper` is still a component which needs to return either a valid HTML or `null`. The solution is just a workaround to make your requirement work. Good catch, let me update to `null`, I like that one better. I did additional test with `null` value, that worked as well. If the solution works and answers your question, feel free to accept as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put a regex in your `path`

```
<Route path='/(bar|foo)/' component={MyComponent} />
```

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router#answer-43877138)