# React Router: Multiple paths to one element

Tags: reactjs

How can I set up multiple Paths to one element with Routers?

It used to be like:

`<Route path = {['example1','example2',...,'exampleN']} element = {<Test />} />`

How do I get the same result in the newest Version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [having multiple paths to the same component in react-router-dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70228810/having-multiple-paths-to-the-same-component-in-react-router-dom-v6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple path names for a same component in React Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40541994/multiple-path-names-for-a-same-component-in-react-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the array to create the Route elements:

```
{["/", "/home"].map((path, index) => {
        return (
          <Route path={path} element={
              <PageWrapper>
                <Home />
              </PageWrapper>
            }
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
```